# How to calculate the words length in JTextPane

Tags: swing, user-interface, text, fonts, jtextpane

I am not mean the length of a string, I mean the words length.... for example...

[image]

As you can see that "This is a testing." is shorter than "THIS IS A TESTING.". But how can I get the different between these two words length, also, I would like to know the position of the text, do I enable to get these information from JTextPane? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

JTextComponent has methods to convert between model and view coordinates:

```
int docEnd = myTextPane.getDocument().getLength();
Rectangle r = myTextPane.modelToView(docEnd);
```